# Should i assert that a validation-method is executed?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I have a question about a unit test i'm writing for existing code.

In the code some input validation is done. The code for the validation is in a separate class, so the code under test calls `ComponentValidator.Validate(request)`.

**The question is: should i unittest that the validate method is called (on the ComponentValidator class) in the code under test?**

I am not sure what to think: one part says "*yes, it's important so check it*", the other part says "*no, you shoudn't test every line of code the method executes because then i am to much bound to the implementation in my unit test*"

If not, the question ends here, but if i should, is there a way to check if the call was made in my unit test, without creating an interface for the validator and mocking it?

I know i can create an interface for the validator, inject it in the class and use a Mock object (i'm using Moq) for it during test, but i don't always want to do that.

Comment: Not sure i understand correctly, but... couldn't you just set up an invalid input state and make sure that the validator catches it? That is, no mocking, but use the real thing.

Comment: Yeah, but the validator is tested in a seperate unit test. So in this test i assume it works, i only want to make sure the validator is called. (at least, that's my question: should i unit test that the validator is called or am i then to much bound to the implementation?)

Comment: You don't need to replace the validation tests, just use it as a sign that it has been called.

Answer (score 1):

As you say that the validator is tested in a separate unit test, you can assume that the validator is working properly.

Assuming the validator is working properly I do not thing that you need to test if the validator is called properly. Think about the following question and what you would do about it :

"I unit tested the Console.WriteLine() method, should I test if it is called properly"

From my point of view, you are going too deep by testing if the validator is called. Unit-testing the module calling the Validator should test if the purpose of the module is met. Not if the every sub-call are made properly.

Edit : Of course, the answer also depends of the unit you want to test. Maybe if you could paste here the unit, it would be easier to provide a more accurate answer

Answer (score 1):

Think what should happen when whatever you test doesn't pass/pass validation. And test if that happens. It doesn't matter that your code calls another class to validate.

What I mean:

`int SomeMethod(someparams)
{
   if (Validator.AreValid(params))
   {
        return -1; // or throw or error code or whatever that you will test for
   } 
   // do some work
   //return some result
}`

Now you write two tests. One with valid and one with invalid params.
Then you test that your method returned what it should in both cases. Calling Validator inside is implementation detail in my opinion.

I would only mock Validator if I couldn't use real one in test (if it for example had to go to database to read validation rules).

Answer (score 0):

I have seen similar scenario in MVC where code similar like this

```
someMethod()
{
  TestHelper.TryValidate(model); // TestHelper is another class where validation is being done
  if(model.IsValid)
  {
      return true;
  }
  else
  {
    return false;
  }

}
```

Here, Just pass the test data such that once it is valid and once it is invalid, after that you can verify result whether expected true/false is returned or not.
Mocking `TryValidate` does not make sense in this case.